# Spreadsheets created using gspread are being shared with all users in my organization

Tags: python, google-drive-api, gspread

I have a Python script that parses an HTML file and puts the information I need from it into a Google Sheets doc that is created by the service account and shared with me. Everything works fine EXCEPT for that the resulting service-account-owned spreadsheet is shared not just with me, but with everyone in my G Suite organization. Not a huge deal since my organization is very small, but I'm sure my coworkers don't want these files cluttering up their "Shared with me" folder.

I've web-searched the heck out of this and perused Stack Overflow but haven't come up with any ideas for changes to my code to try. I also wondered if it might be a setting I need to change in the Google API Console, but haven't found anything there either.

Here's the relevant code:

```py
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def loadTemplate(template_name, output_name):
        # use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API

        print("Connecting to Google API...")

        scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
        client = gspread.authorize(creds)

        # Make a copy of the template and name it something that uniquely identifies this report

        print("Copying template...")

        open_spreadsheet = client.open(template_name)
        copy_spreadsheet = client.copy(open_spreadsheet.id,title=output_name, copy_permissions=True)
        copy_spreadsheet.share('myname@myorganization.com', perm_type='user', role='writer', notify=False)

        return copy_spreadsheet

template_spreadsheet = loadTemplate(template_name, output_name)
```

Again, everything runs as expected, except the result is shared with all users in my G Suite organization instead of just with me (myname@myorganization.com). Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Weirder still - I tried removing the share() and now the file isn't shared with me, but IS shared with everyone else in my domain. This makes me think it's something to do with the service account credentials I'm using or some setting in the Google API console, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, and I feel pretty stupid...

I was copying a template, and set `copy_permissions=True`. The template was not in fact shared with my whole organization, but it *was* shared with the two people I happened to check with, and as a result every copy of it was by default shared with the same two people. Changing to `copy_permissions=False` fixed the issue.